# Python 3.x A program thats control if some requirments true

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch, assertions

My purpose with this program is to take input from student and make sure that
he/she typed 3 digit number. Neither less than 3 or greater than 3 and it shouldnt be string. All this above  if something wrong, program should ask again until its become true

```
def studentID():
       try:
           number=int(input("sutedent IDS:"))
           try:
                assert len(number)==3

           except AssertionError:
               print("Must be 3 digit number.")
               studentID()

       except ValueError:
           print("Please enter an integer.")
           studentID()

       except TypeError:
           print("What is wrong with you?")
           studentID()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int`s don't have a `len`.  You'll have to convert it back to a string to check its length.

```
def studentid():
    try:
        num = int(input('student ID:'))
        if len(str(num)) != 3:
            print('Please enter a 3-digit number')
            return studentid()
        return num
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a 3-digit number')
        return studentid()
```

You also probably want to return the `num` to the caller.  Note that we cast the input to an `int` then back into a string.  This is because in some recent versions of Python (3.6+), you can have underscores in `int` literals, so `int('1_2')` would be a valid 3 character input that evaluates to a 2 digit number

Comment: You were getting `TypeError`s because you were trying to do `len(n)` where `n` is an `int`.  As `int`s don't support `len`, that raises a type error.  That shouldn't happen in the above.  If it somehow does raise a `TypeError`, you should let it stop the program so you can identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to add to Patrick's comment, i would prefer range(len(3)), it's clear and it's also more efficient. 
How I would do tho

```
def studentID():
       number=int(input("sutedent IDS:"))
       if range(len(number)) == 3:
           return studentID()
        elif number is not int or range(len(number)) > 3 :
             print('please enter a valid number')
             return studentID()
        else:
             raise ValueError
             return studentID()
```

Comment: I did not understand what you wrote . And also it is not working